# Go gin-framework gin.Context.Param() giving wrong values

Tags: http, go, url-routing, go-gin

Here is simple code that i am trying

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    server := gin.Default()

    server.GET("/countries/*code", GetCountries)
    server.Run()
}

func GetCountries(c *gin.Context) {
    ccode := c.Param("code")
    log.Printf("Code: %s", ccode)
}
```

I have extracted code from url and log it.
Here is output after running and accessing urls

```
[GIN-debug] redirecting request 301: /countries --> /countries/
Code: /
[GIN] 2016/07/16 - 17:24:59 | 200 |      16.508��s | ::1 |   GET     /countries/
Code: /USA
[GIN] 2016/07/16 - 17:25:17 | 200 |       12.47��s | ::1 |   GET     /countries/USA
```

In output, you can see, it is giving code along with the "/". 
If there is no code in url still it is giving "/"

Is it a bug or expected behaviour of gin?
Do i need to check for "/" to know whether code is actually passed or not?

Comment: `server.GET("/countries/:code", GetCountries)`

Comment: *code is optional, :code will make it mandatory, that is not the objective.

Comment: Maybe play about with `server.RedirectTrailingSlash = false`

Comment: @MartinGallagher i just tried your suggestion, but it doesn't make any change.

Comment: Could be a limitation of Gin; this is my workaround: https://play.golang.org/p/Hmc2HOUQMD

Comment: It seems to match anything after and including the slash, so if you did "/counties/usa/newyork" it would match "/usa/newyork" keep that in mind if you end up using it.